# Parameters missing or not sent as an JSON array with PHP CURL

Tags: php, json, curl

The error:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":0,"error":{"code":1,"message":"Parameters missing or not sent as an JSON array. "}}
```

My code:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json","Accept: text/plain, */*; q=0.01")); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/rpc/ClientApi?_session=XX');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array('method' => 'AdsApi.giveAdLifeByCategory','params' => '["Ads4Life"]', 'id' => '0')));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

I'm trying to emulate this request:

```
[{"method":"AdsApi.giveAdLifeByCategory","params":["Ads4Life"],"id":0}]
```

Correct Response:

```
[{
     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
     "id": 0,
     "result": {
         "status": true,
         "timeStamp": 0
     }
}]
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong bracketing:

```
... 'AdsApi.giveAdLifeByCategory','params' => '["Ads4Life"]', 'id' => '0')));
                                               ^---       ^--
```

your "emulated" sample has braockets around that, but you're embedding them in your array key definition, so when the JSON is produced, it'll actually be:

```
... "params": "[\"Ads4Life\"]" ...
```

with the `["` and `"]` embedded within the string.

Probably should be just

```
... 'AdsApi.giveAdLifeByCategory','params' => array('Ads4Life'), 'id' => '0')));
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Tried `array('method' => 'AdsApi.giveAdLifeByCategory','params' => 'Ads4Life', 'id' => 0)` And still getting the same error.

Comment: AH yeah. the ads4life is actually an ARRAY inside the json string, so you have to define it as an array at the PHP level. updated the "should be" section in the answer.

Comment: Oh, Thanks. That worked. :) Great man. can accept answer in 1min.